# XPCOM object method is unaccessible from JavaScript

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying to build an extension for Firefox. This extension uses an XPCOM component (a C++ dll). I'm compiling the DLL, compilation is OK.

I also succeeded in building a JS code which instanciates the object from XPCOM:

```js
try {
   greenfox;
   return true;
} catch( e ) {
   alert( e );
   return false;
}
```

The object returned is this one:

```
QueryInterface
    QueryInterface()

__proto__
    [xpconnect wrapped native prototype] { QueryInterface=QueryInterface()}

QueryInterface
    QueryInterface()
```

Everything is fine, except I can't call the function which are supposed to be in my XPCOM component.

Here is my IDL file:

```c++
[scriptable, uuid(ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384)]
interface nsISample : nsISupports
{
    attribute string value;
    void writeValue(in string aPrefix);
    void poke(in string aValue);

    void start();
    double stop();
};
```

When callingstart() function, I get the Javascript error: "is not a function"

```js
greenfox.start();
```

Do you have any idea? It seems like no function is exposed in my XPCOM.

Comment: It would have helped if you actually wrote here how you instantiate your XPCOM component.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking at an object exposing only the `nsISupports` interface. Your interface (`nsISample`) won't get exposed by default, you have to explicitly request it. You can do it for example by instantiating your component like this:

```js
var greenfox = Components.classes["..."].getService(Components.interfaces.nsISample);
greenfox.start();
```

Alternatively, you can also call `QueryInterface` on an object you already have:

```js
greenfox.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISample);
greenfox.start();
```

Generally, I wouldn't recommend using a binary XPCOM component for reasons outlined [here](http://adblockplus.org/blog/binary-xpcom-components-are-dead-js-ctypes-is-the-way-to-go), maintaining them requires way too much effort. I would rather suggest compiling a regular DLL and using it via [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes). [Reference a binary-component to js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175608/reference-a-binary-component-to-js-ctypes-firefox-addon/6257595#6257595) mentions how you would locate a DLL inside your add-on to use it via js-ctypes.

Comment: That's a lead, and I also found this code in the sample given by Mozilla. I already tried it before, but when trying to get instance, I get this message: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsISupports.QueryInterface]"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://greenfox/content/greenfox_sampler.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 11"  data: no]

Comment: I'm going further: I examinated Components.interfaces and I found no nsISample in it.

Comment: @frinux: That means that the XPT file with your interface wasn't registered. Either you didn't include it in your extension or the [`interfaces` entry in `chrome.manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#interfaces) is incorrect.

Comment: I'm following your advice Wladimir, I also thinks XPCom are too complicated and I'm trying to do it through js-ctypes. J'm still stuck in the library definition, you can see my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152142/mozilla-use-a-c-dll-with-js-ctypes

Answer (score 0):

Do you call QueryInterface with your uuid? It is necessary to call it before using the component instance created. Does your usage match what's in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.classes)?

If you don't want to deal with XPCOM you can use [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes).

Comment: -1 for using swearwords without explaining the issue. Altogether this is borderline to "not an answer".

Comment: Sorry, I assumed people who have trouble finding the right documentation would read it given the pointer instead of my possibly inadequate explanation.