# Mozilla use a C DLL with js-ctypes

Tags: c, firefox, dll, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm tying to build a dll, and then use it with a Firefox extension.

I managed to build a DLL using gcc under Windows :

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int a,int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

I try now to use it through my dll. After reading some posts, especially this one, I couldn't manage to make this work: [Reference a binary-component to js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175608/reference-a-binary-component-to-js-ctypes-firefox-addon/6257595#6257595)

Each time I try ctypes.open, I have the error message: **couldn't load the library**. However, the DLL path is correct. Here is the JS code:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");

AddonManager.getAddonByID("greenfox@octo.com", function(addon)
{
    var libcPath = addon.getResourceURI("components/library.dll");

    if (libcPath instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIURI)
    {
        var libc = ctypes.open(libcPath.path);

        var libc = ctypes.open(libc);

        /* import a function */
        var puts = libc.declare("add", /* function name */
                   ctypes.default_abi, /* call ABI */
                   ctypes.int32_t, /* return type */
                   ctypes.int32_t, /* argument type */
                   ctypes.int32_t /* argument type */
          );

          var ret = puts(1,2);

          alert("1+2="+ret);

    }
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you specify `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` in `install.rdf`?

Comment: Yes, and I checked in the folder containing the extesion : the DLL is there

Comment: The path collected from libcPath is this one : /C:/Users/frinux/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/y8d4d4lq.default/extensions/greenfox@octo.com/components/library.dll

Comment: And I also tried to move this library to C:, and then call ctypes.open("C:/library.dll"); but no success

Answer (score 1):

The path part of the URI is not what you want to have here - you want the file path:

```js
if (libcPath instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL)
{
    var libc = ctypes.open(libcPath.file.path);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFileURL)

Comment: Yes I tried that first (I followed your stackoverflow post about it first). The path is good, but still have this error. I wonder if my DLL is OK? It compiled, but is there any way that it is unuseable? How could I test my DLL?

Comment: I posted a new question, as it seems the problem does not come from the JS but from the DLL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348604/build-a-dll-tu-be-used-by-mozilla-js-ctypes