# Build a DLL to be used by Mozilla js-ctypes

Tags: dll, firefox-addon, mozilla, jsctypes

In reference to my first post: [Mozilla use a C DLL with js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152142/mozilla-use-a-c-dll-with-js-ctypes)

I'm trying to build a DLL to be used from a Mozilla Firefox extension. I created a little C code and compiled it with GCC.

Here is the C code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int a,int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

Here are the compilation lines:

```
gcc -c library.c
gcc -shared -o library.dll library.o -Wl
```

The DLL is well compiled, I can open it with dllexp and can see the add() method exposed.

The problem is, when I try to use it from my extension, I always get the message: **Error: couldn't open library**

Here is my Javascript call:

```
var libc = ctypes.open("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll"); //OK
var libc2 = ctypes.open("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\library.dll"); //KO
```

It seems the DLL cannot be opened by Firefox, but I wonder why. I don't see anything about building DLL for Firefox extension, it seems we can use every classic DLL library.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile the library like that you get a dependency on `msvcrt.dll` which probably cannot be resolved on your system ([redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555) required), on mine it works fine. You can compile your library without the dependency on the CRT, you just have to define `DllMain` yourself:

```c
#include<windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  return TRUE;
}

int add(int a,int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

And the link step looks like this:

```
gcc -shared -nostdlib -o library.dll library.o -Wl,-e_DllMain@12
```

You cannot use CRT functionality then - I couldn't find a way to compile the runtime statically with GCC on Windows (Visual C++ on the other hand does it just fine).

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot I would never been able to do it without your help Wladimir, for this ticket andalso fot the previous others!

Comment: To be more precise, only the declaration in the C file is required. The compilation line, with -nostdlib, will prevent the code to run kernel32 function