# Making a C DLL in Visual Studio suitable for use by js-ctypes in Mozilla

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, dll, jsctypes

As the subject says, what I'm trying to do is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348604/build-a-dll-to-be-used-by-mozilla-js-ctypes) but using Visual Studio 2012.

I can build and produce a DLL, and I can load that DLL in javascript, but I cannot access the function in that DLL. Looking at the DLL in DllExp shows no functions, suggesting something's wrong with the DLL.

The DLL is a new C++ project created using the "Empty Project" template. Notable settings are;

General->Configuration Type set to DLL
No optimization.
No precompiled headers.
Compile as C code
Calling convention __cdecl

The commandlines for compilation and linking, in case there's a setting I've not thought significant, are

```
 /GS /TC /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\StreamInterop.pch"
```

And for linker

```
 /OUT:"C:\Work\VehicleTracker-DotNet\StreamInterop\Debug\StreamInterop.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Work\VehicleTracker-DotNet\StreamInterop\Debug\StreamInterop.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:\Work\VehicleTracker-DotNet\StreamInterop\Debug\StreamInterop.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Work\VehicleTracker-DotNet\StreamInterop\Debug\StreamInterop.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\StreamInterop.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBI
```

The project contains a single C source file, main.c, containing

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int add(int a,int b)
 {
     return(a+b);
 }
```

Given this is all that was needed in the earlier post, it seems to me the problem must be in the compiler or linker switches. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Hey! I have similar problems here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381478/exporting-functions-in-msvs-2013-in-c-c-dll-for-mozilla-js-ctypes-to-use. Is your DLL using 64bit or 32bit code?

Comment: 32 bit it seems- the linker commandline is specifying kernel32.lib amongst others. See Mark Tolonen's comment below regarding how to actually create the project- that pushed a lot of the difficulties away into the wizard.

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to find a solution, finally, by myself. It is on the previous link I provided, if you are interested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows using Visual Studio, to export a function from a DLL, use:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a,int b)
 {
     return(a+b);
 }
```

As a side note, don't choose Empty Project so Visual Studio will generate some example code for you.

Comment: Thanks. That gets it working, though don't understand why the previous poster didn't need it. Chose empty project because the only specific DLL project is "MFC DLL" and I was worried that'd produce something dependent on some framework that'd stop it working from js-types.

Comment: Choose `Win32 Project`, then `DLL` and `Export symbols`.  `gcc` exports everything.  VS requires explicit exporting.

Comment: Ooo. Thanks, didn't know that wizard existed.