# Exporting functions in MSVS 2013 in C/C++ DLL for Mozilla js-ctypes to use

Tags: dll, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

I am trying to access some exported functions from a MSVS 2013 C/C++ DLL via FireFox's js-ctypes.
I have tried :

- Changing the "Compile As" settings to C and C++
- Changing the platform bitness (32 vs 64 bits).
- Using ALL the available ABI constants from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ctypes (`default_abi`, `stdcall_abi`, `winapi_abi`)
- I have checked my DLL using "Dependency Walker" and made sure that its name was not decorated and that my function was indeed exported.

Here is my DLL code:

```
#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DllExport void Test()
{
    ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("Test!"), _T("Title"), MB_OK);
}
```

No matter what I try, it seems that I always get this error:

```
 console.error: myxpi:
   Message: Error: couldn't find function symbol in library
   Stack:
     openScratchpad@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///c:/users/kgk/appdata/local/temp/tmpdyrqfd.mozrunner/
 extensions/jid1-QEiY1nT1Uinqug@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-qeiy1nt1uinqug-at-jetpack/myxpi/lib/main.js:34:18
 button<.onClick@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///c:/users/kgk/appdata/local/temp/tmpdyrqfd.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-QEiY1nT1Uinqug@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-qeiy1nt1uinqug-at-jetpack/myxpi/lib/main.js:16:9
```

Does anyone have any idea what are the proper settings?

FF is 32 bits (as far as I know) but I don't know if it uses something else like python to load the DLL.

I thought that the "Compile As" wouldn't matter as long as the exporting functions used the proper declaration (e.g. `__cdecl`).

I am not sure what this produces though (but my project settings are for `__cdecl`):

```
#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

But I have tried replacing that too and using DEF files...

Any idea why nothing seems to wok?

Related questions:

[Making a C DLL in Visual Studio suitable for use by js-ctypes in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221741/making-a-c-dll-in-visual-studio-suitable-for-use-by-js-ctypes-in-mozilla?lq=1)

[Build a DLL to be used by Mozilla js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348604/build-a-dll-to-be-used-by-mozilla-js-ctypes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK. Here is what I've used:

- Build settings for 32bit platform (from config. manager).
- Calling convention: __cdecl (/Gd)
- Compile As: Compile as C++ Code (/TP)
- Using no DEF files (Linker->Input->Module Definition File)
- This code:

  ```
  #define DllExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
  DllExport void Test()
  {
          ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("Test!"), _T("Title"), MB_OK);
  }
  ```

JS:

```
    var lib = ctypes.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\myXPI\\lib\\MyAddonCore.dll");
    var test = lib.declare("Test", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.void_t);
    test();
    lib.close();
```

You have to define a `void` argument for functions with no arguments (it's for the return value as `Kinjal Dixit` pointed out below)!

Unfortunately this didn't find the DLL path (I wonder why... :| ):

```
var lib = ctypes.open(self.data.url('MyAddonCore.dll'));
```

Cheers!

---

**Update:**

And here is some code to get the DLL path :

http://www.acnenomor.com/3342758p1/how-to-load-dll-from-sdk-addon-data-folder

```
    const {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require("chrome");
    Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
    const ResProtocolHandler = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
    const ChromeRegistry = Cc["@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1"].getService(Ci.nsIChromeRegistry);

    function resolveToFile(uri) {
        switch (uri.scheme) {
            case "chrome":
                return resolveToFile(ChromeRegistry.convertChromeURL(uri));
            case "resource":
                return resolveToFile(Services.io.newURI(ResProtocolHandler.resolveURI(uri), null, null));
            case "file":
                return uri.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file;
            default:
                throw new Error("Cannot resolve");
        }
    }

    var self = require("sdk/self");
    let dll = self.data.url("test.dll");
    dll = resolveToFile(Services.io.newURI(dll, null, null));
    console.log(dll.path); // dll.path is the full, platform-dependent path for the file.
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for sharing. Please tag your future posts with firefox-addon, not too many people browse jsctypes but they always do that firefox-addon tag, I totally missed this topic.

Comment: to clarify the point about "you have to define a void argument for functions with no arguments", it is actually the void return type that you are setting there.