# Building a DLL that includes libraries for Mozilla js-ctypes

Tags: gcc, dll, firefox-addon, mozilla, jsctypes

I'm trying to build a DLL to be used in a Mozilla Firefox extension. I'm using Cygwin in Windows 7. I have the C code working fine and it builds ok:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  return TRUE;
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a,int b) //int a,int b
    {
        return(a+b);
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions here: [Build a DLL to be used by Mozilla js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348604/build-a-dll-to-be-used-by-mozilla-js-ctypes).

The problem is that when I try to include a different library, the js-ctypes cannot read the DLL afterwards:
`[10:20:53.575] Error: couldn't open library C:\Users\admin\workspaces\Extensions\formfinder\components\test.dll @ chrome://formfinder/content/overlay.js:104`

All I'm adding to my C file is `#include <ZZ.h>` at the top, which is then complemented by the make commands:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -I/usr/local/include/NTL -I/usr/local/include test.cc  
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o test.dll test.o -Wl,--out-implib,libmylib.dll -Wl,-e_DllMain@12
```

I'm using `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` instead of `gcc/g++` because the DLL can't be opened otherwise. I'm not sure why though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I created a library to call from my firefox extension with js-ctypes and it works fine.  Unfortunately, I have only tried this on ubuntu linux, so I'm not sure what your problem is.  However, I had the same problem until I found somewhere that it is necessary to specify a compiler switch to specify "position independent code".  That switch was -fPIC on the gnu compilers.  I'm not 100% sure this is your problem, but find out which switch you need and try it.  Who knows, maybe that's your only problem.  I don't know for sure you need position independent code on windows too, but maybe you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get what is asked, but probably why the Cygwin gcc (or mingw-w64 gcc) is producing a DLL you cannot `ctypes.open()`.

DLLs produced by the Cygwin gcc do have external dependencies on some Cygwin DLLs, at least `cygwin1.dll` providing a posix abstraction.
Shipping these DLLs with your add-on is a pain and not really a sane thing to do.

You'll want to use a mingw compiler (e.g. the `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` one). You could also use a Microsoft or Intel compiler instead.

OK, mingw-w64 it is for now:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o test_add.dll test_add.cc
$ objdump -p test_add.dll
The Import Tables (interpreted .idata section contents)
...
DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
...
DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
...
The Export Tables (interpreted .edata section contents)
...
[Ordinal/Name Pointer] Table
        [   0] add
```

Alright, our DLL imports `kernel32.dll` and `msvcrt.dll` and nothing unexpected, and also exports our `add`.

Lets try it, then:

```
var lib = ctypes.open("C:\\cygwin\\home\\user\\test_add.dll");
try {
    try {
        var adder = lib.declare("add", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.int32_t, ctypes.int32_t, ctypes.int32_t);
        console.log(adder(3,5));
    }
    catch(ex) {
        console.error(ex, ex.message);
    }
}
finally {
    lib.close();
}
```

Produces an output of: `8`.

Next, all binaries should be ASLR enabled.

```
$ peflags -v test_add.dll
test_add.dll: coff(0x2106[+executable_image,+line_nums_stripped,+32bit_machine,+dll]) pe(0x0000)
```

Turns out, it isn't (no dynamicbase)

So let's improve our linker command:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o test_add.dll test_add.cc -Wl,-nxcompat,-dynamicbase
$ peflags -v test_add.dll
test_add.dll: coff(0x2106[+executable_image,+line_nums_stripped,+32bit_machine,+dll]) pe(0x0140[+dynamicbase,+nxcompat])
```

Alright then.

But this is not all, unfortunately. When compiling `C++` and using certain features, the linker will automatically link in the `stdlibc++`, e.g. when using `std::string`.

Adding a `std::string` to our source, recompiling/relinking, and another `objdump` tells us:

```
DLL Name: libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
7470       16  _Unwind_SjLj_Register
7488       17  _Unwind_SjLj_Resume
74a0       19  _Unwind_SjLj_Unregister

DLL Name: libstdc++-6.dll
vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
74bc      743  _ZNSaIcEC1Ev
74cc      746  _ZNSaIcED1Ev
74dc     1080  _ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
74f4     1105  _ZNSsD1Ev
7500     3535  __gxx_personality_sj0
```

In that case, you'd have to ship those libaries as well (make sure to `peflags` the ASLR bits and follow the license), or avoid anything that could produce an exception or would otherwise require `stdlibc++`.
Or you can static link the stuff:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o test_add.dll test_add.cc -Wl,-nxcompat,-dynamicbase -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Static linking will blow up the output DLL size, of course.